# Calulating a mean coefficient effect based on quantile regression estimates

Tags: regression-coefficients, quantile-regression

I have used quantile regression to estimate a particular coefficient for the 10th, 20th, ... 90th percentiles.  Now, I want to estimate the mean effect of the coefficient across the whole distribution.  Using ordinary least squares to estimate the mean effect, however, is inappropriate given the heteroscedastic, non-Gaussian distribution of the model errors.  Would it be appropriate to use the mean of the quantile regression estimates as an approximation of the coefficient's mean effect?

Comment: Inappropriate in what sense? Which quantiles would you average and why would that be anything but a biased - indeed, inconsistent - estimate the mean of a skewed distribution?

Comment: I agree with @Glen_b . I'd add that, if you want something *similar* to estimating the mean, rather than averaging a bunch of regression coefficients, why not just use the median?